# Iwconfig obsolete, is there a sensitivity setting for IW?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-roaming

Older versions of linux used:

> iwconfig dev sens -80

To set the roam sensitivity, after the signal dropped below the set threshold, the card/adapter would initiate a scan looking for another AP to roam to.

I'm being told that iwconfig has been obsoleted in favor of using IW for cards that use mac/cfg80211.

This answer from **Grawity** seems to confirm that: [iwconfig command not showing abgn](https://superuser.com/questions/1329621/iwconfig-command-not-showing-abgn?r=SearchResults)

The IW man page isn't really of any help:
https://linux.die.net/man/8/iw

This wiki has alot of information, but nothing on sensitivity: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw

It's rare that I have to do this at all, but every once and a while I get sticky linux clients trying to hold on to an AP long after they should have roamed. I prefer installing Atheros based wireless cards if that makes any difference.

So the question comes down to:
Does anyone know of any way to perform some CLI wizardry to set the "roam agressivness" with **iw** from the command prompt?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

`iw` apparently has no equivalent for the sensitivity threshold.
The article
[Deprecated iwconfig commands](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/#iwconfig)
for the sub-command `iwconfig [interface] sens [threshold]`,
only says this in the Replacement column : "Not apparent".

A non-CLI vaguely alternative setting is found
in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wireless`.

You can set in this file the parameter
`SENS=1|2|3` for selecting the sensitivity level of the access point,
although not with the same precision as with `iwconfig`.

For example documentation, see for Red Hat the article
[Setting Up a Wireless LAN](http://etutorials.org/Linux+systems/red+hat+linux+bible+fedora+enterprise+edition/Part+IV+Red+Hat+Linux+Network+and+Server+Setup/Chapter+15+Setting+Up+a+Local+Area+Network/Setting+Up+a+Wireless+LAN/):

> **SENS** — You can select the sensitivity level of the access point. SENS can be set to 1 (low density), 2 (medium density), 3 (high density). The default is 1. The sensitivity threshold has an impact on roaming.

Comment: I can't help with that approach.